# Where is memory allocated for a string variable inside method?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-memory

If  we declare a `string` variable inside a method, will its memory be allocated in the Stack or in the Heap?

```
class Test
{
    public void display()
    {
        string str = "sujeet";
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test _test = new Test();
        _test.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even care?

Comment: on stack every local var  stored in stack head is for global var

Comment: @zixrobert *head* is for thinking... but all reference types (class, like `string`) are stored in the heap (in regular .Net Framework) whether they are local variables or fields. Which indeed covered multiple times on SO and everywhere.